# How to restrict access to Jenkins?

Tags: authentication, jenkins, configuration, authorization

My Jenkins instance is currently open for every user, there is no authentication. I want to protect Jenkins against access by unauthorized users. I'm looking for a very simple/basic solution -- one user. If this "`admin`" user hasn't authenticated himself, he should not be able to do anything. If he has, he should get the full access the Jenkins instance (including all projects). How to configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Go to **Configure Global Security** --> **Security Realm : Jenkin's own user database** and authorization **Logged-in users can do anything**. After saving, Jenkins should prompt you to create a new user. Please create the required user by filling in details like username and password.

Then, log in with that user and change the authorization to **Matrix-based security**. The matrix configuration should be as shown below i.e., it should have all privileges for the required user and none for anonymous users.

[image: Jenkins Security Settings]

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create an admin user or whatever you want.

To do that, go to your jenkins dashboard page and find **"Credentials"** option. 
In credentials, you can create your user.

With your admin user created, just go back to your jenkins dashboard page and find **"Manage Jenkins"** option, in there, click on **"Configure Global Security"**.

In Global Security Page, check the box **"Enable Security"**, scroll down to **"Access Control"** and chose **"Jenkins’ own user database"** and select what users can do after login.